# CentOS: How to set hostname based on external file in kickstart script?

Tags: centos, kickstart

I install CentOS 7 using the `ks=http://10.0.0.100:8080/anaconda-ks.cfg` option and I serve the static configuration file by running a simple web server: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`.

In my `anaconda-ks.cfg` I currently set the hostname like this:

```
network  --hostname=centdev
```

However, I wish to read a text file (preferably JSON using Python) from the same location as my `anaconda-ks.cfg` and check the current hardware ID against a dictionary to figure out which hostname to use.

1. Can I somehow avoid hardcoding http://10.0.0.100:8080 into `anaconda-ks.cfg` and fetch this location via e.g. a an environment variable?
2. Do I just embed my python script inside of `anaconda-ks.cfg` using the `%pre` like below?

---

```
%pre
#!/bin/python
print 'Read JSON file here...'
%end
```

Comment: Nobody said you have to request a static file. The URL can be a script which you run and dynamically generate a kickstart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did... I added the following into my `anaconda-ks.cfg` script:

```
# Pre python
%pre --interpreter=/usr/bin/python
print 'python code goes here to define "myhostname"'
...
hfile = open("/tmp/hostname.ks", "w")
hfile.write("network  --hostname=" + myhostname)
hfile.close()
%end

# Network information
network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0 --ipv6=auto --activate
%include "/tmp/hostname.ks"
```

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer, even if it is your own. Nice that you got it working, you can put whatever you like in pre and post scripts.